# Content of Mac Application not resizing on entering fullscreen mode

Tags: macos, fullscreen, nssplitview

I am developing a mac application using an NSSplitView.  There are 3 columns, a menu on the left, an NSTableView in the middle and a detail view on the right.  All my components use constraints and none of them are set to restrict width or height

When I press the button to go into fullscreen mode, the application does go fullscreen, however the actual content doesn't resize, it just stays the same and a large black border forms around the application.

What are the possible causes for this and how do I debug to find out where the issue lies?

[image: osx fullscreen content not resizing]